# How can I animate my views with the NSLayoutConstrains (auto layout) workaround?

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, ios6, autolayout

I'm working to get my apps configured for the new iPhone 5. So I started with investigating the auto-layout guide of cocao touch ([link][1]) and the WDC masterclasses.

But still one thing is unclear to me. How can I animate my views.

In my previous Apps I used the regular UIView animation like:

```
            [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
            MyView.frame = CGRectMake(0,100, 100, 100);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Or the CGAffineTransform methods.

Can someone tell me what the best workaround is when working with auto-layout, since I'm unable to refer to frames and don't make frame-declarations anymore? Settings timers and removing and adding constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraints are really not at all related to the animations.

However, you should use the up to date block based animation methods such as `animateWithDuration:animations:`.

Comment: Nice thank you, it works. I'm however having one bug in there. I've got two views setup; one above the other. When pressing a button the above view moves to the left for 320 pixels. However it doens't start at it's regular point (lets's say (0,0) but at (-320,0). Can you explain this?

Comment: @Mundi:but how view will animate without using Frame or any constraint? would you like to elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, when you use Auto-layout all the **setFrame** methods are removed. In your case if you want the View to move about certain number of pixels you can try moving the **center** of the view instead of setting the frame of the view and set the priority of the constraints around the view to low.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
[MyView layoutIfNeeded];
```

in animation block.